# how to swap div elements in sortable jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Codepen **[Demo](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/YqbdJq)**

Here i used **sortable jQuery** .Only  Answer Block - 1,2,3,4,5  are sortable Blocks not Block 1,2,3,4,5. aboce code working only to move the elemets.

But need swap elements.

if drag **4th elements** to 2nd place Result like this   **1-2 4-3- -5.**
the 4th place is empty.

But my expectation  results like this  **1-4-3-2-5**

JS Code :

```
$(".right-block").sortable({
          connectWith: '.right-block',
        opacity: 0.6, cursor:"move",               
          cancel: ".unsortable" , 
            revert:true,
           items: "span",
         placeholder: "highlight",
                start: function (event, ui) {
                        ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
                           ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());                       
                },          

                stop: function (event, ui) {
                        ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
                }       
        });
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid... you cant place `<li>`s inside a `<div>` that too without UL or OL

Comment: @RRR : yes,but i need that . if any other way pls share it . thanks :)

Comment: kindly refer https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/646yef8d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each item is in it's own sortable for you specific case, you can use the [receive](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) callback like:

```
receive: function(event, ui) {
  ui.sender.append($(this).find('span').not(ui.item));
},
```

[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grJEPq)

Judging by your use case, if you only want to swap elements I think it's better to use draggable + dropable.